# Marker with title for Google Maps iframe and coordinates

Tags: google-maps, iframe

I want to embed Google maps on my website using `iframe` and the coordinates of the desired location. I found two ways of doing this. One requires an API key. One doesn't. However, none of them allowed me to set a name / title on the marker. It's basically just a plain marker in the middle of something, without any useful information.

With API key, I tried this

```
<iframe
                    width="100%"
                    height="400"
                    frameborder="0"
                    scrolling="no"
                    marginheight="0"
                    marginwidth="0"
                    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=<MY_KEY>&q=50.068842, 8.645633&zoom=15">
                </iframe>
```

The result:
[image]

Without API key:

```
<iframe
                    width="100%"
                    height="400"
                    frameborder="0"
                    scrolling="no"
                    marginheight="0"
                    marginwidth="0"
                    src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=50.068842, 8.645633&hl=en-US&amp;z=14&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed">
                </iframe>
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

Is there any way to show that the place at the marker's location is called `Deutsche Bank Park`?

Otherwise, it doesn't really looks like it's of much use for the regular user.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use embedded iframe? 
If not, this will be an easy task with API key and a little bit of JS.

Comment: Iframe allows me to use a simple front-end solution. I imagine that for any solution that involves an API key I need to switch to a back-end solution which could complicate things a lot.
However, what would be the alternative you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this snippet. You can add multiple markers only with HTML, just follow the syntax. You can also style with CSS the infowindow as you please.

```js
function initMap() {
  const uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  
  const infos = document.querySelectorAll('.infowindow');
  
  infos.forEach(info => {
    const content = info.innerHTML;
    const lat = info.getAttribute('data-lat');
    const lng = info.getAttribute('data-lng');

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content
    });
    
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.infowindows {
  display: none;
}

.infowindow__content {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<div class="infowindows">
  <div class="infowindow" data-lat="-25.363" data-lng="131.044">
    <div class="infowindow__content">
      <p>You can set simple HTML here and it will goes to the marker</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to hide your API Key you should keep it as secret in BE.
But, I don't think that this is necessary anymore as you can restrict the key to be used for specific URLs, which means that no one can use it for its website.

Answer (score 0):

If Google Maps knows about the place, you can use that place name (Deutsche Bank Park) in the query string:

```html
<iframe 
    width="100%" 
    height="400" 
    frameborder="0" 
    scrolling="no" 
    marginheight="0" 
    marginwidth="0" 
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Deutsche Bank Park&hl=en-US&amp;z=14&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lkobyjwe/1/)

[image: screenshot of result]

Comment: I haven't found a way to use both coordinates AND the name. Coordinates are the main way to identify a location

Comment: Do you not have the name of the places?

Comment: Yeah, I do have the name but it doesn't replace the coordinates. For some weird places, the name might not be on the maps, but the coordinates will not fail to display the right location